# Evaluuating a determinant full of expresions in terms of the roots of a quintic

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know how to do the following problem.

Suppose that $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $x_{3}$, $x_{4}$, and $x_{5}$ are roots for the equation $x^{5}-2x^{4}+x^{3}+1=0$. Let $a_{ij}=1+x_{i}x_{j}$ for $i=j$, and $a_{ij}=x_{i}x_{j}$ for $i\neq j$, where $1\leq i\leq 5$ and $1\leq j\leq 5$. Evaluate
  \begin{vmatrix}
   a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & a_{15}\\
   a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & a_{25}\\
   a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} & a_{35}\\
   a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} & a_{45}\\
   a_{51} & a_{52} & a_{53} & a_{54} & a_{55}
  \end{vmatrix}

Comment: You should get comfortable with the definition of a determinant.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Actually, this does not require to know more than the determinant of a diagonal(izable) matrix.

Comment: @julien: True. Regardless to that, being comfortable with the definition of a determinant allows one to sit and unravel the matrix and to preform the needed calculations, even if that would be the longer and bruteforce attempt at solving the problem. There is a *huge* difference between posting "I don't know how to do it" and "I know the answer is $X$, but I did that by a bruteforce method. Is there a shorter way to derive it?"

Answer (score 1):

First observe that all the $x_j$'s are nonzero since their product is $-1$, by looking at the constant term of the polynomial.

Now note that 
$$
A=I_5+B\quad\mbox{with}\quad B=(x_ix_j).
$$
It is clear that $B=xx^T$ is of rank $1$, so $0$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ with multiplicity $4$.

Now 
$$
\mbox{tr}\;B=x_1^2+\ldots+x_5^2.
$$

Using [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) for the power sums $s_k=\sum_{j=1}^5 x_j^k$ of the roots of the polynomial
$$
t^5-2t^4+t^3+1=t^5-a_1t^4+a_2t^3-a_3t^2+a_4t-a_5,
$$
we have
$$
s_2=a_1s_1-2a_2=2\cdot 2-2\cdot 1=2.
$$

So the trace yields a distinct eigenvalue. Hence $B$ is diagonalizable with diagonal $(0,0,0,0,2)$.

It follows that $A=I_5+B$ is diagonalizable with diagonal $(1,1,1,1,3)$.

So 
$$
\det A=3.
$$